# How to make a {x,y,z} plot of a data set

Tags: plotting

I'm a beginner using Mathematica so I really need help with this.

I have a data set which consist in a [X,Y] vector and a matrix of Z values. For every step of Y, I have a vector X, which is always the same, and a set of Z values (every row of the "Z" matrix is a set for each step). So, I have, for example:
{X[1...vector lenght],Y[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPGni.png),Z[MatrixRow 1]} as my first set of values.
I need to put them all in the same 3D plot, but I'm not sure about how to do it.

Thank you and sorry for my english :c
[image: dataset for a certain Y]

[image: the result would be something like this, but the axes are wrong bc the plot is wrong lmao]
1st image is a dataset for a certain Y
2nd, the result would be something like this, but the axes are wrong bc the plot is wrong lmao

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! I'm a bit confused about the structure of your dataset and what you want to plot. Is `X` the same length as `Z[[row]]`, and do you want to plot points in 3D by lining these up? So, for example, if `{X, Y, Z[[row]]} == {{1,2,3}, 5, {4,5,6}}`, would you want to plot the points `{1,5,4}, {2,5,5}, {3,5,6}` in 3D? Or have I misunderstood? Can you include a small example of what you're working with?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, both, X and Z[[row]] have the same length. And yes, u got it right, i have attached some examples in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your data structure right, then one straightforward way to do this is by the following:

```
datapoints = Flatten[Array[{X[[#1]], Y[[#2]], Z[[#2, #1]]} &, {Length[X], Length[Y]}], 1]
```

`Array[f, {n,m}]` creates an `n` by `m` array of entries of the form

```
{{f[1,1], f[1,2], ... , f[1,m]},
 {f[2,1], f[2,2], ... , f[2,m]},
 ...
 {f[n,1], f[n,2], ... , f[n,m]}}
```

The anonymous function `{X[[#1]], Y[[#2]], Z[[#2, #1]]} &` in place of `f` uses the first argument to get `i`th part of `X`, the second to get the `j`th part of `Y`, and the `j`th row of `Z`, `i`th column. `Flatten[<...>, 1]` then flattens the array made by `Array` at the first level, down into a simple list of points in 3D.

(This is equivalent to `Flatten[Table[{X[[i]], Y[[j]], Z[[j, i]]}, {i, Length[X]}, {j, Length[Y]}], 1]`, in case that's clearer.)

Then `ListPointPlot3D[datapoints]` can get you a scatter plot, and `ListPlot3D[datapoints]` can get you a mesh like the orange one pictured above.

Let me know if I've misinterpreted or if this doesn't work!

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. Really <3 I updated the post with the plot